# ICMP Disable/Blocked:How To Check Internet Connection Using C#

Tags: c#, icmp, internet-connection

If ICMP Is Blocked/Disabled by Administrator. Is there any way to check the internet connection through C# when ping test is not possible.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it yet, but I think the following works.

```
HttpWebRequest req;
HttpWebResponse resp;

req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

if(resp.StatusCode.ToString().Equals("OK"))
{
      Console.WriteLine("its connected.");
}
else
{
      Console.WriteLine("its not connected.");
}
```

I think this will do the job, and it might be required to add 'System.Net' or so to the usings.

Comment: I have to add, I think creating a response to a simple page like google.com, or even more simple, 'example.com' might give a faster result. But then, I'm not sure if the GetResponse loads the whole thing in memory already, or does just a response check to see if it can be accessed.

Comment: I just found another method, but it's using some DLL to check internet connectivity, the solution can be found at: http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/264358-How-check-whether-internet-connection-exists.aspx

Comment: instead of url,use Ip Address to check the internet connection.

Comment: name/url would be better, servers (ip addresses) go offline/online all the time